# OpenCV Error: GStreamer unable to start pipeline

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, gstreamer, opencv3.0

I am developing a program which has a functionality that allows to open and preview video inside one of qtwidgets. I am trying to make it run for at least last three days without success. I tried on a different machines with Arch Linux and Windows and it runs perfectly (I also tried on the same machine with W10 and it is working fine). I don't want to install other OS only because of that. Below I have attached simple example that produces the same runtime error.

```
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
int main()
{
    cv::VideoCapture("path_to_file_that_exists.mp4");
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the result:

```
libva info: VA-API version 0.39.4
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_0_39
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0
libva info: VA-API version 0.39.4
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_0_39
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0
GStreamer Plugin: Embedded video playback halted; module qtdemux0 reported: Internal data stream error.
OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (GStreamer: unable to start pipeline
) in cvCaptureFromCAM_GStreamer, file /home/user/Documents/opencv-build/opencv-3.1.0/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp, line 818
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /home/user/Documents/opencv-build/opencv-3.1.0/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp:818: error: (-2) GStreamer: unable to start pipeline
 in function cvCaptureFromCAM_GStreamer

Press <RETURN> to close this window...
```

- OpenCV 3.1.0
- GStreamer 1.10.1
- Linux 4.8.0-1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.8.7-1 (2016-11-13) x86_64 GNU/Linux

**EDIT**

I haven't found the exact answer to my question. After compiling Gstreamer with plugins from sources (version 1.4, 1.6, 1.8, 1.10) I had the same problem with video (In couple versions I haven't got a problem because I wasn't able to load single frame of video at all) I decided to change distribution to my old one - Arch Linux, because it doesn't have this problem (I really don't know why).

- OpenCV 3.1.0
- GStreamer 1.10.1
- Linux 4.8.10-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon Nov 21 11:55:43 CET 2016 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Hi I also have the same problem, but when you write the GStreamer (VideoWriter) it is not working, I want to ask you how did you compile OpenCV with GStreamer? Here when I compile it says: GSTREAMER_glib_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND .... , do you know why, my System is Win10 64bit. Thanks!!

Comment: Had the same issue. Turned out that the video file was corrupt!

Comment: @BahramdunAdil Compiling OpenCV on Windows is fun as hell. I done that in the past but not recently. You can try this solution https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/8836#issuecomment-341318892

Comment: @bialy Man, I asked that question 2 years ago haha, OK, thanks anyway. But compiling OpenCV with GStreamer is very easy now for me.

Comment: @BahramdunAdil I have noticed, but there were many times where I had problems and only topics on SO that I was able to find were unanswered - I hate that :)

Comment: @bialy Hmmm, I got it, OK thank you!